# BNF / EBNF for Turbo Pascal (preferably 5.5 or later, because of OOP)?

Tags: language-agnostic, bnf, ebnf, turbo-pascal

Does anyone of you know if the BNF or EBNF of Turbo Pascal is available somewhere (LEGALLY!!)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will [Delphi 5](http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/compilers/delphi_5_grammar/delphi_5_grammar.html) do?

Comment: Not really, sorry, because the goal is to compile TP 7.0 in the end. :-)

Comment: @Turing Complete: Isn't there already a TP 7.0 compiler?  Why do you want another?

Comment: Delphi is a superset of ObjectPascal.

Comment: Ira, the idea is to compile TP 7.0 with a very sophisticated runtime environment that even simulates part of the hardware into IL.

Comment: @Ignacio

True, you are right. I will accept your answer now, I checked the link and it's perfect. :-)

Comment: Where did you get TP sources from?

Comment: Note that the Delphi grammars are afaik not the exact grammar used, but just for documentation purposes.

Comment: @Turing Complete: Are you done with it (TP7 grammar & the runtime environment)?

Answer (score 2):

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is a commercial platform for building program analysis and transformation tools.  It is configured by providing it with an explicit BNF grammar for the langauge to be processed.

DMS can be obtained with a Delphi 6 front end.  This has been used to implement AOP for Delphi.

Building other dialects is straightforward.

EDIT: (respond to comment by OP on another answer):
DMS would be a very convenient platform on which to build a compiler.